# How do I source in "/Users/<usr>/.ghcup/env" to $PATH in .zshrc after installing Haskell?

Tags: shell, osx, zsh, path, haskell

I cannot seem to get the `$PATH` variable sourced in via `/Users/chris/.ghcup/env` so that I can directly use the `ghc` or `ghci` binary in `zsh`.

I installed ghc & cabal-install via ghcup: `curl https://get-ghcup.haskell.org -sSf | sh` as described on https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html / https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/

Hint during installation process:

> It will add the 'cabal', 'ghc', and 'ghcup' executables to bin directory 
>   located at:
>
> `/Users/chris/.ghcup/bin`
>
> and create the environment file `/Users/chris/.ghcup/env`
>   which you should source in your ~/.bashrc or similar to get the required
>   PATH components.
>
> ...
>
> In order to run ghc and cabal, you need to adjust your PATH variable.
>   You may want to source `'/Users/chris/.ghcup/env'` in your shell
>   configuration to do so (e.g. ~/.bashrc).

I can get the binaries to run after adding `export PATH=/Users/chris/.ghcup/bin:$PATH` to `~/.zshrc`. However, from the hints during installation I am assuming that I should rather use the `$PATH` information automatically provided in `/Users/chris/.ghcup/env`.

Content of `cat /Users/chris/.ghcup/env`:

> export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:${GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX:=$HOME}/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"

How do I incorporate that into my `.zshrc`?

Comment: Just `. /Users/chris/.ghcup/env`? However, if you're on macOS, it would be slightly easier to install `ghc` via Homebrew, especially if you're already using Homebrew for other packages.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Just add `. /Users/chris/.ghcup/env` it to `.zshrc`? Like this?:
`% cat .zshrc
. /Users/chris/.ghcup/env`

Comment: That would source the file as part of sourcing `.zshrc` whenever an interactive `zsh` shell start, yes.

Comment: @Kusalananda: thanks that flxed it. You can post that as an answer if you want to also get the credit for helping. Also, I was trying to get around Homebrew as I read that versions are not always up-to-date and there might be other differences.

Comment: The most recent version of GHC is 8.8.1 (25 August 2019).  This is also the version available through Homebrew on macOS. The GHC people themselves mentions installing the software via Homebrew (see [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/distribution_packages.html#macosx)). They don't seem to _recommend_ it, but there is no reasoning mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to source the file `/Users/chris/.ghcup/env` from your `~/.zshrc` file.  This can be done by using the dot (`.`) utility in your `~/.zshrc` file like so:

```
. /Users/chris/.ghcup/env
```

If `/Users/chris` is your home directory, then this may be shortened to

```
. ~/.ghcup/env
```